# When ApplicationID is generated in Membership.CreateUser method?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I was working with ASP.Net Membership and was wondering when exactly ApplicationID is generated. I want to know what events are called and when does ApplicationID is generated when we use "Membership.CreateUser" method.

I googled it for some time but couldn't find any satisfactory answer.

Can anyone explain what is the working of this method?

Thanks

Comment: Which `ApplicationID` are you referring to?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, the ApplicationID I am refering to here is the column name in "aspnet_Membership" table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know what events are called and when does ApplicationID is
>   generated when we use "Membership.CreateUser" method.

Right before processing any request to Membership table (such as select/insert/update/delete), **Application** is retrieved by **applicationName**.

For example, inside the **Membership.CreateUser** method, **QueryHelper.GetApplication** is called right before creating a new user.

```
Application application = QueryHelper.GetApplication(membershipEntity, 
   applicationName);

// QueryHelper.GetApplication
internal static Application GetApplication(MembershipEntities ctx, 
   string applicationName)
{
    ObjectParameter[] objectParameter = new ObjectParameter[1];
    objectParameter[0] = new ObjectParameter("name", 
       applicationName.ToLowerInvariant());
Application application = ctx.CreateQuery<Application>(
"select value a FROM Applications as a WHERE ToLower(a.ApplicationName) = @name",
objectParameter).FirstOrDefault<Application>();
    return application;
}
```

If **application** is null, it is created an application like this -

```
internal static Application CreateApplication(MembershipEntities ctx, 
   string appName)
{
   Application application = new Application();
   application.ApplicationId = Guid.NewGuid();
   application.ApplicationName = appName;
   ctx.Applications.AddObject(application);
   Application application1 = application;
   return application1;
}
```

About code is from [ASP.NET Universal Providers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx). Legacy Membership Provider uses Store Procedure, but the logic is almost same.